# Word template not found via bookdown word_document2

Tags: r, shiny, bookdown

I have trouble creating a word document via shiny app. I want to use a specific word template which lives in the same folder as the app, together with my markdown. This works for the normal `output: word_document` as it should. But for `output: bookdown::word_document2` it does not use the template.

There are some similar questions to mine, but those use the standard `word_document` and **NOT** `bookdown::word_document2`.

The download handler copies the template together with the report to the temporary folder and knits the document. I have commands to list files in the temp folder and it lists the word template, so it seems to be there. When I knit the document by hand, it works fine. But via the download button from the shiny app, it does not use the word template.

I don't know how to provide my template here in SO. But what I did in my template is to change color for H1 and H2.
I uploaded it to dropbox, hope it will stay there for a while.
[myTemplate.docx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bb92br1zwq7hgrg/myTemplate.docx)

`app.R`

```
library(shiny)

temp_folder <- tempfile()
dir.create(temp_folder)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("headline1", "H1", value = "Headline 1"),
    textInput("headline2", "H2", value = "Headline 2"),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  
  
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "myReport.docx",
      content = function(file) {
        tempReport <- file.path(temp_folder, "myReport.Rmd")
        file.copy("myReport.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
        tempTemplate <- file.path(temp_folder, "myTemplate.docx")
        file.copy("myTemplate.docx", tempTemplate, overwrite = TRUE)
        params <- list(
          headline1=input$headline1,
          headline2=input$headline2
        )
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, 
                          'word_document', 
                          output_file=file,
                          params=params,
                          encoding="UTF-8",
                          envir=new.env(parent=globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

`myReport.Rmd`

````
---
title: "reference test"
output:
   bookdown::word_document2:
    reference_docx: myTemplate.docx
    
params:
  headline1: NA
  headline2: NA
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(bookdown)
headline1 <- params$headline1
headline2 <- params$headline2
```
# my written headline

# test `r headline1`

test test

## my written second level headline

## test `r headline2`
```{r}
print(list.files())
print(getwd())
```

1 2 3
````

Comment: Haven't tested your code. But you have set the `output_format` to `'word_document'` in `render`. Perhaps that's the issue. I would try with removing that line so that the output format is taken from the Rmd.

Comment: I tried a similar approach in parallel... Looks like I can define those settings there as well with for example `bookdown::word_document2(reference_docx='myTemplate.docx'),` So it seems this is the solution... If you like, please write an answer. I will try without setting the output in the render function.

Comment: Great. A second approach would of course be to set the output format and the reference docx in your `render` call.

Comment: somehow it was not intuitive for me since it was a string and not a function... But in the documentation on the render command, it showed an example to use the function `word_document()` with options... Than it came to my mind. Thanks!